# Calculate raster volumes within polygons - GDAL & Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, area, volume

I have a shapefile with 625 polygons.
I have a .tif raster DEM file at a 1m resolution.

Objective: get 625 values that describe the volume of the raster (above 0m elevation) within each polygon. (since the resolution is 1m, that would be the sum of all the values above 0 inside the polygon)

Context: the polygons are wards of London (625 regions within London), I need to know the built up volume within each ward.

Complication: the raster only partially covers the area covered by the shape file. I only want the volume within a polygon to be calculated if the area of raster coverage within the polygon = the area of the polygon itself (i.e. if raster data is only available in parts of the polygon, I would like to write volume as  as 0/NA)

Comment: Use the rasterstats package, zonal_stats() function. It will compute raster statistics for a given shapefile. If you want more control, you can add keyword arguments to return a 'mini_raster_array', which will give you the clipped raster for each polygon. Then you can compute whatever stats you want (and throw out those with too much nan).

Comment: geocube might be able to assist with this: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/zonal_statistics.html